# Spring Using Kotlin instead of Java for Big Scope Web dev Project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

I'm just learning Spring framework for about a Month and the great things is, run directly new Small Project using it. And I do lot of exploration and learn new stuff in Spring. I figure out there's Kotlin Integration Support with Spring.

Is that safe and stable to build Big Application using Kotlin instead of Java ?

And again its **not just RESTful Api** .. but would Kotlin do all the Web Task ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have no idea of what you mean by "all the Web Native Task" though. Will you really be more comfortable to use what Spring provides in a stable release when some random stackoverflow users like me tell you: "yes, it's stable"?

Comment: haha .. sorry, because Kotlin do most in Mobile & REST services but how about Big Web Application ?

Comment: What's the difference in your mind between "REST services" and "Big Web Application"? Anyway, this is unclear and off-topic. If you're afraid, then experiment.

Comment: REST its for AP,I but I mean It's real Web Apps like Amazon Market Place. I never found developer using Whole Web Programming using Kotlin